# Google Cloud Platform: App Engine dispatch.yaml limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Good day,

Our company has started getting rid of VMs and servers and are moving all our applications over to Google Cloud Platform. We currently use 1 production GoogleCloud Platform Project and we have multiple applications deployed on App Engine. We use a dispatch.yaml file to route incoming requests to the correct App Engine services. However, we have recently ran into a problem with too many dispatch.yaml file records.

Please see example below of some entries:

- url: "*sabreakingnews.com/*"
  service: sabn
- url: "c-api.connector.com/*"
  service: c-api
- url: "*myride.mobi/*"
  service: myride

We have many more applications we need to move over to Google Cloud Platform, but we need a better solution to map all these domains to an App Engine service. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is to just create another Google App Engine (GAE) project.

If there is no common code between all the domains, you could create a separate GAE project for each domain.  This is cleaner in my opinion.

If some domains have common code and some do not, then you could put domains with common code in the same GAE project.

If all domains have common code, then you have a few options:

- use symlinks to share common code (this is easier with GAE standard)
- make a library for common code and add the library to each GAE project
- use GIT submodules to share common code

I don't know if Google has a limit for GAE projects but you should find that out before committing to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want them hosted on one service or not.. Separating what you need for microservices is IMO required for any big project, and what GAE is designed for. Example would be a frontend service which wouldn't need any large cpu, and would just be designed for serving the browser frontend (JS/HTML/CSS etc.).

The api should definitely be on another service / server (at the start they recommend B class I believe?) F being frontend, B being backend. Then you can rate-limit the API or limit based on IP, and have the frontend visible and always on.

In the end, if it's a large scope like that I would definitely recommend Kubernetes. While developing you can also setup kubectl with minikube for local development. The pods would be your different services.

Skaffold can also help with rapidly syncing your dockers. Once you get into the Docker/Container world, there really is no turning back! Once you have the appropriate containers per service, you can spin up an instance group with your services that are based off Google Container OS which link to your gcr.io container images.

You'd need to setup a Load Balancer, map your custom domains within the Load Balancer to map to your instance group, and viola. At that point you'll have health checks (that you can create while creating a Load Balancer) that will monitor your services and if any are down the Balancer would route to ones that are up.

Sorry for a lot of information, hope it goes well for you guys!

Answer (score 0):

[App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) is a great solution for simple apps/services you're trying to build. Every GCP projects gives you one App Engine which can have up to 20 services. Also see for reference (links are for Python, but you can offlink to your supported language from each page):

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_multiple_services
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/communicating-between-services

If your needs extend beyond this description, then it's likely you should consider another product such as [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.run), both sister products to App Engine in the suite of [Google Cloud serverless](https://cloud.google.com/serverless) products.

- Cloud Functions is a product tailor-made for microservice architectures
- If your code is part of a CI/CD pipeline where you plan to or are currently using containers, you should use Cloud Run instead; see [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build) for more info on Git-push-to-deploy (CD) and [this community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cicd-cloud-run-github-actions) featuring GH Actions (CI/CD)
- If you use Cloud Functions' [Functions Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework) to develop your functions locally, when deploying, they're put into a container and execute on Cloud Run
- Instead of being limited to 1 App Engine app with up to 20 services per GCP project, both Cloud Functions and Cloud Run can deploy up to 1000 functions/services per region
- Cloud Functions and Cloud Run services can also be deployed to multiple regions (unless App Engine which is tied to a single region)
- Here's a [3-part blog post series](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/serverless-from-the-ground-up-building-a-simple-microservice-with-cloud-functions-part-1) on Cloud Functions microservice architectures
- For those with mobile needs, there's a Cloud Functions derivative: [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), naturally suited for mobile microservice architectures
- Google Cloud Functions is best if you need to access other GCP tools/services while Cloud Functions for Firebase is for those with mobile apps built with Firebase, Google's mobile development platform. More on choosing between them [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/functions-and-firebase)
- Cloud Functions and Cloud Run have one other important feature App Engine does not yet have: background events (triggering execution); with App Engine, it can only be HTTP. See [GCF events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers) and [GCR Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/build-event-driven-applications-in-cloud-run) for more info.